# ChartJS Stacked Bar- but always stay on 100% on y-axis

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jze1kr6u/2/

```
    const data = [{"band_1_correct":"16","band_1_total":"20","band_2_correct":"15","band_2_total":"20","band_3_correct":"12","band_3_total":"20","band_4_correct":"15","band_4_total":"21","band_5_correct":"13","band_5_total":"19","band_6_correct":"0","band_6_total":"0"}];

 
 var correctCounts = [];
    var totalCounts = [];
    var difficultyLevels = [];

    var difficultyData = data[0]; // Access the first element of the array

    // Iterate over the difficulty levels
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        var levelKey = 'band_' + i;
        difficultyLevels.push('Band ' + i);

        var correctCount = parseInt(difficultyData[levelKey + '_correct']);
        var totalCount = parseInt(difficultyData[levelKey + '_total']);

        if (totalCount === 0) {
            correctCounts.push(0); // Handle division by zero case
        } else {
            var correctPercentage = (correctCount / totalCount) * 100;
            correctCounts.push(correctPercentage.toFixed(2));
        }

        totalCounts.push(100); // Set total count to 100%
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('barChart1').getContext('2d');
    var barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: difficultyLevels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Correct',
                    data: correctCounts,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                    stack: 'combined' // Stack the bars
                },
                {
                    label: 'Total',
                    data: totalCounts,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                    stack: 'combined' // Stack the bars
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: 100, // Set y-axis maximum to 100
                    stacked: true // Stack the bars
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (context) {
                            var label = context.dataset.label || '';
                            var value = context.parsed.y || 0;
                            if (label === 'Correct') {
                                return label + ': ' + value + '%';
                            } else {
                                return label + ': 100%';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Above is the working code of the chart, but What i wanted to do is, Y-Axis will be always 100%, so for example on Band 1 (the band_1_correct is 80%), so it will filled up 80% of band_1_total, instead of stacking up

Tried couple of method from other post such as adding : `stacked: false,` not helping the issue i am facing

Comment: Maybe you can try by https://github.com/y-takey/chartjs-plugin-stacked100 plugin

Comment: @user2057925 it's not working for me, added plugin and enabled it, stil lshowing the same issue